# Node graph editor

Tags: c#, .net, graph

Is there a .NET library for creating node graphs, one that lets you drag inputs on one node to outputs on another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) and [Graph#](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/). HTH.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give those a look. I also found this
http://www.nwoods.com/

Answer (score 4):

This is more or less exactly what you are looking for:

- https://github.com/LogicalError/Graph